# Conditional formatting only certain cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a column containing various different numbers (days until something has to be completed) and have set up the conditional formatting in such a way that small numbers will be reddish and large numbers will be greenish. In the column to the right there is a binary value "done" or "not done" indicating whether the task has been completed.

Now I want to make it so that if the value to the right is "done" the cell in the number column will automatically format to green. What I have done is set the default to green and used a rule to only format those the cells for which the value to the right is "not done". However, here I am only able format all cells for which the value to the right is "not done" in the same way. I want these cells to be formatted in the way described in the first paragraph.

Any ideas on how to implement this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please upload a simple example worksheet with your rule (Dropbox, OneDrive etc). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Try to provide a sample about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

‘Conditional Format’ has multiple options for the rule; the most advanced is ‘Formula’. If you choose that, you can make *any* rule you like, of any complexity.
You’ll probably need something like `AND(col1 =“val1”,col2=“val2”)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set this up is to use two Conditional Formatting ("CF") rules and set the first-rule-looked-at's `Stop If True` checkbox to "checked."

You have the current rule, no problem, no matter what kind of rule it is, one of their preset ones or one with a formula.

When you enter the CF functionality ("Conditional Formatting Rules Manager"), you will see the existing rule. Click the `New Rule` button in the upper left to insert a new rule before the existing rule.

For the new rule, edit it to use a formula as its test and use a formula like:

```
=B1=1
```

(For your data being in A1 and the binary value for Done/Not Done being in B1. It will then apply that side-by-side test to the whole range you specify.)

Be sure to check the `Stop If True` checkbox to the extreme right on that rule's line.

Another thing to be sure of is to make the `Applies to` range the same as for the now second rule. Copy that second rule's range and Paste it into the range box for the new rule. They will then adjust similarly if Excel adjusts them in the future.

The key is the `Stop If True` checkbox. When checked, Excel stops if the job has been marked completed and never evaluates the second rule.

Also, be sure to set the actual format! Get lucky right off, or try various choices until it sets the right green for you. (Or maybe you'd like a different color altogether as these being the same color as one used for the other purpose might be confusing or distracting for your users.)